# $X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))=\sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

We have a random vector $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I would like to know if $X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is equivalent to $\sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$.

Notation: $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the Borel field in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\sigma$ refers to the $\sigma$-algebra generated.

My solution: If $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $$X_i^{-1}(B)=X_i^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{i-1}\times B\times\mathbb{R}^{n-i})\in X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)), $$
therefore $$\sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}\subseteq X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)). $$
Let $\mathcal{D}=\{B_1\times\cdots\times B_n:B_i\text{ open in }\mathbb{R}\}$. We have $\sigma(\mathcal{D})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))=X^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{D}))=\sigma(X^{-1}(\mathcal{D}))$. Now, 
$$ X^{-1}(B_1\times\cdots\times B_n)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n X_i^{-1}(B_i)\in\sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}, $$
so $X^{-1}(\mathcal{D})\subseteq \sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ and 
$$\sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}= X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)). $$

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Can you tell us what are $\sigma, X, S, S_1,\dots, s_m, X_1,\dots, X_n$? You are missing a lot of context.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is explained in the link. $S=(S_1,\ldots,S_n)$ and $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ are random vectors, $\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and $\sigma(S)=S^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$, where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borelian sets. $\sigma\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}=\sigma\{X_i^{-1}(B):i=1,\ldots,n,\,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$, where $\sigma$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated.

Comment: @user372906: Every post on this site is expected to be reasonably self contained. Since you expect people to take the time to answer your question for free, you are expected to show a little bit of effort and respect by providing all the necessary details in an orderly fashion in the body of your post (not in a comment). If your post looks like you couldn't be bothered to write it, why should people be bothered to answer it? Rewrite your post to make it self contained and easy to understand, and I'll answer it.

Comment: Yes, people should not have to read comments nor follow links to understand a question, except in rare circumstances. There is simply no reason you couldn't have repeated the post simply by copying and pasting. Help people help you.

Comment: @Evan Aad The question is written clearer.

Comment: @user372906: You did well, but there was still room for improvement. I edited your post and made those improvements. Take a look and see the difference. The changes are: 1. I have deleted the reference to your other question, because it's entirely irrelevant to your current question. 2. I have cut off redundant information that does not add to the question at hand. There is no need to ask about both $X$ and $S$. If this question can be solved for $X$, then the same answer applies to $S$. You see what I'm saying?

Comment: @user372906: Unfortunately, by now the question has been put on hold by moderators, so I can't answer it until it is reopened. I have placed a "reopen" request, and we need to wait for a few other people to place a "reopen" request before this question can be reopened and made available for answering. I'm not sure whether you can place a "reopen" request, but if you can - do it. It's as easy as clicking the link the says "reopen" at the bottom of your post.

Comment: @user372906: I've also changed the title of your post to match the updated content. You left the title the same as for the other post. Please take note of all these changes, so you can write good posts in the future on your own.

Comment: @user372906: You need 2 more votes for your question to reopen. Based on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423), I suggest you leave a comment addressed to Thomas Andrews, who may have voted to close your question, and ask him to consider voting to reopen it, in light of the recent updates. Then leave another comment, addressed to no one in particular, asking for other users to vote to reopen, seeing as you've edited your question to a better form.

Comment: And what about the notion of... well, *personal input*? I must have missed how there is any in the present question.

Comment: @user372906: Yes, your solution is, on the whole, correct. Well done!